# jQuery Datatables plug-in not working with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatables

I am trying to add more functionality to a table in my MVC application by using the jquery [datatables plug-in](http://datatables.net/). I have added the following to my index.cshtml page to try and turn the table 'dailyreporttable' from a standard table into a datatable:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dailyreporttable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

However when I preview the page in the browser, the datatables plus in has not been applied to the table, and it remains as a standard table. I don't have any experience with MVC or web development so I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try switching your script references. The browser loads scripts in order, and jQuery needs to be referenced before jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You should be adding these references to your BundleConfig.cs file.

You will probably have a bundle being loaded in _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myBundle")
```

So add the jquery and datatables reference to that particular bundle, e.g:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myBundle").Include(
     "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
     "~/Scripts/DataTab....ataTables.js"
));
```

You can check that the js files are being loaded by looking the the Firebug Net tab (if you're using Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reference to the css file??
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../media/css/jquery.dataTables.css"

Comment: Yeah i have added the reference to the CSS file but it still doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

try changing the order of script loading :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTab....ataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Because `datatables` jquery based plugin and it requires jquery methods to run, so you have to include jQuery library first so that all the required methods gets available to the `datatable` plugin.

Comment: Just tried that and the same thing is happening. Do I need to add references to the script elsewhere, such as the BundleConfig.cs file or _layout.cshtml file? this is my first time using scripts in MVC so I am not sure about what is the correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dailyreporttable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="dailyreporttable">
</table>
</body>
```

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dailyreporttable').dataTable();
```

just move it out of the document.ready()

that seemed to do the trick for me,

another approach would be to use the ClientID